# How can I create/remove folders in Shinyapps.io?

Tags: directory-structure, shinyapps

I would like to

- view the folder structure of my apps that are deployed in my shinyapps.io account
- also create/remove folders if necessary

What is the best way of doing this? Can I use Filezilla for that purpose? If so, how?